# Set onClickListener For Whole Screen

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout

Hello Iam Fairly New To Kotlin

I Heard That You Can Set **onClickListener** for the **whole screen** in java.

so I was asking

1-Can You **Do the same thing in kotlin?**

2-How to set **onClickListener** for **constraint-layout** in **kotlin?**

*and thanks in advance*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set click listener to whole screen

```
findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).rootView.setOnClickListener{
        // do something here
    }
```

Comment: It Only Works When I Remove The **".rootView"**

Answer (score 1):

Give id to your `constraint layout` and do something like this

```
constraintlayoutId.setOnClickListener{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

> Can You Do the same thing in Kotlin?

Yes you can since Kotlin can use all the Android APIs which were written in Java so there won't be any problem

> How to set onClickListener for constraint-layout in Kotlin?

Give your `ConstrainyLayout` and ID and then use `findViewById`, `ViewBinding`, or ... the get a reference of it inside your Activity/Fragment/View and call `setOnClickListener` on it and do anything you want inside of it

Answer (score 0):

So, `ConstraintLayout` is just another `View` and so if you want to set a click listener to it you just need its reference and call the method `onClickListener` on it.

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.yourConstraintLayoutId).setOnClickListener { 
     // Do something here
}
```